# ¿Cómo puedo generar un formulario y que se repita?

Tags: php, html

Quiero generar un formulario un número de veces establecido por mí; yo ingreso en un input el número de veces que se va a repetir el formulario, pero cuando lo hago se repite de corrido. Yo quiero hacer para enviar uno, y que me salga el siguiente, y almacenar los datos en un array. ¿Cómo lo hago?

```
<body>
    <form action="practica3.php" method="post">
        <h1>Dame el numero de alumnos registrados</h1>
        <input type="number" name="alum" id="alum">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="uno">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["uno"])){
    $alum = $_POST['alum'];
    $inicio = 1;
    while ($inicio <= $alum) {
    ?>
        <form action="practica3.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Alumno Nº <?php echo "$inicio"; ?></legend>

        <p>¿Que edad tiene? <input type="number" name="edad"></p>

        <p>¿Eres Chico o Chica? <select name="kesos" id="kesos">
            <option value="chico">chico</option>
            <option value="chica">chica</option>
        </select>
        </p>

        <p>¿Publica o Privada? <select name="a" id="a">
            <option value="publica">publica</option>
            <option value="privadaca">privada</option>
        </select>
        </p>

        <p>¿Cual fue tu promedio al terminar? <input type="number" name="pro"></p>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
        $inicio++;
    }      
    
?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="dos">
    </form>
    <?php
    }  
    ?>
```

Este es mi código. Quiero hacer que no se ponga el formulario uno debajo de otro; quiero cargar el primero y que despues de llenarlo, y darle a enviar me salga el siguiente, así sucesivamente hasta llegar al número establecido antes.

Comment: Creo que te has rendido un poco pronto. Tienes que usar un poco más la imaginación, piensa en lo que necesitas para que se comporte de la manera que quieres. Cuando ya tengas una idea de cómo podría funcionar, es hora de trasladarlo a código PHP. Ánimo.

Comment: debo introducir un numero de personas, y cada persona sacar unos datos, para que asi formule cuantas personas entras a cierta categoria, como por ejemplo: 12 personas, de esas 12 personas decir cuales son hombre y mujeres, no se como hacerlo T_T

Comment: metelo en un bucle y le dices cuantas veces quieres que se repita; pero evita usar los "id" ya que no se deben duplicar...

Answer (score 0):

Algo que debes saber: En PHP orientado a web (no **php-cli**), el script se **ejecuta totalmente**. O sea, procesa las órdenes, manda la salida HTML y *muere*. Si el script quedara esperando órdenes, el navegador se colgaría.

Hay varias formas de resolver tu problema: mandando un contador como `input hidden`, con sesiones, con una base de datos, etc.

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo usando **hidden**. En esta propuesta el contador `$i` se envía en el parámetro escondido `'idx'`. Cuando se le da ENVIAR, nuevamente `$i` valdrá `0`, pero no por mucho tiempo ya que entrará al primer `if`, captura el valor de `idx` y sobreescribe `$i`.

En el siguiente `if/else` se pregunta si `$i` es menor al `$total`, si es así, se intrementa `++$i` y se dibuja el formulario (para ello usé una función, pero puedes prescindir de ella si quieres).

```php
<!-- cabeceras HTML -->
<?php
function generar_formulario($i) {
    ?>
    <h3>Formulario <?php echo $i;?></h3>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        - Aqui van los inputs - <br />
        <input type="text" name="input1" value=""><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="idx" value="<?php echo $i;?>">
        <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
    </form>
    <?php
}

$total = 3; // <-- Total de veces que se dibujará el formulario
$i = 0; // <-- Contador

if(isset($_POST['idx'])) {
    echo 'Valores capturados: <br />' . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($_POST); // <-- Data cruda enviada
    $i = $_POST['idx']; // <-- sobreescribe $i
}

if ($i < $total) {
    generar_formulario(++$i); // <-- Dibujar formulario
} else {
    echo '<p>Ya fueron generados todos los formularios</p>';
}
?>

<!-- Pie y cierre HTML -->
```